# How to move pivot to center of an array object?

Tags: modifiers

I have copied the default cube with the array modifier.

I can rotate my camera around the center of the cubes by pressing "shift + c".

How can I set the pivot to the center of the cubes? I could do it by setting the 3D cursor in the center and then set origin to 3D curser, but how do I get the 3D cursor in the center? Do I have to calculate the position by hand and set the coordinated componentwise, or is there also a shortcut?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one hackish way to do it, taking advantage of the fact that positioning the 3D cursor is not undo-able.

1. Apply the array modifier
2. Enter edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>)
3. Select everything (<kbd>A</kbd>)
4. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>*> Cursor to selected*
5. Exit edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>)
6. Undo twice (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>)

[image]

Comment: the problem is that even though I copied the cube 5 times with the array modifier I can only edit one cube. Setting the cursor to selected will only center the curser to my first cube - in editmode and objectmode. By the way is the blender wiki currently down?

Comment: @Adam You must first apply the array modifier as in step 1 (don't worry, this is undone later). The wiki does appear down.. Wait, now it's back up.